# Matlab multi line plot colorbar and colormap dont match

Tags: matlab, colorbar, colormap

First post here.
I have a bunch of xy data (actually lats and longs), plotted the lines successfully with a scalar value for each line. Scalar values run between 0 and 0.5'ish. Created a colormap and ran it between 0 and 1, based on the native 'autumn' map. I got this far from a couple of other posts, not exactly what I was trying to do but managed to get close using the information provided for others. Issue now is that the relative colorbar that comes up in the plot is all one color??

Here is my script:

```
figure
% Define colormatrix
cols=flipud(autumn(1001));
% Interpolate the COL matrix to get colors for the data
tcols=interp1(0:0.001:1,cols,probS);
set(gcf,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',tcols);
colormap(tcols);
plot(xx,yy);
caxis([0,1])
c=colorbar;
```

It tried to attach an image to show what I mean but was denied as a first time user.
The funny thing is, when I run the same script but substitute the xy and the scalar value (probS) for the randomly generated numbers the colorbar behaves, e.g.

```
close all;clear all
xx=rand(75,25)*10;
yy=rand(75,25)*10;
probS=sort(rand(75,1));

figure
% Define colormatrix
cols=flipud(autumn(1001));
% Interpolate the COL matrix to get colors for the data
tcols=interp1(0:0.001:1,cols,probS);
set(gcf,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',tcols);
colormap(tcols);
plot(xx,yy);
caxis([0,1])
c=colorbar;
```

any advice or ideas would be most appreciated.

Comment: Post the image as a link and we will upload it.

Comment: Nice way of displaying longitude and latitude! However, I think that the problem may have to do with the data somehow. It is a shame that you was not allowed to commit an image, but may I ask what the range is of the colormap and how many lines you have plotted? Still it is kind of weird that your colormap only have one color. Can you try to give more information about your colormap?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your values are in the range 0 to 0.5? Too often i miss a `1e-14*` or the like that is printed on top of a long vector in the command window ... that would explain the single color when scaling to `caxis([0,1])`.

Comment: Ander, not sure on how to do post image as a link, so uploaded to drop box: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m0mwkklsw9h7t8c/fail.png?dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/s/hiqt6yt2bydqn2g/good.png?dl=0

Comment: Hi Patrik, there are some 500 lines plotted. Each line has about 1500 points in it. Have tried reducing the number of lines and points but makes no difference. Not sure what you mean by the range of the colormap.........

Comment: Thomas, not the case, probS are definitely not to the power of anything. Actaully before a run the caxis line, the colorbar is already all one color (yellow) and the ticks are equivalent to the number of lines I am plotting.

Comment: Check what tcols is, maybe it is constant color. If so, the problem is not with the graphical part. Also compare the displayed map with tcols by getting it with `get(gcf,'Colormap')` - if they are identical the problem is within the graphics part. In this case you could try to explicitly re-set the maps data by `set(gcf,'Colormap',tcols)´. If that does not help i am out of ideas. If you want to publish the figure the last workaround is always exporting both the working random figure and the original one and then replacing the bar...